# How to retrieve the records list on a device with ONVIF profile G?

Tags: c++, soap, onvif

On a network camera I've many records. Each record has many tracks (audio, video and Metadata). To create a new record on a camera, you must restart the recording.

With ONVIF profile G I would like to retrieve each record, so I use the GetMediaAttributes method in a C++ code.

```
#include "soapSearchBindingProxy.h"
std::unique_ptr<SearchBindingProxy> deviceSearchBindingProxy = std::unique_ptr<SearchBindingProxy>(new SearchBindingProxy());
_tse__GetMediaAttributes GetMediaAttributes_tmp;
_tse__GetMediaAttributesResponse GetMediaAttributesResponse_tmp;

GetMediaAttributes_tmp.Time = 0;//from beginning

deviceSearchBindingProxy->GetMediaAttributes(&GetMediaAttributes_tmp, GetMediaAttributesResponse_tmp);
```

the response doesn't give me all the record list, it contains just 1 record. The records on camera are melted in that record, but I need to retrieve each record separately.

Is my implementation correct to retrieve the list of records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested 3 cameras from different manufacturers recently and I believe the only way is to retrieve recorded events and then use RTSP to get audio/video fragments using timestamps obtained from this events. Event types vary between cameras.

All 3 cameras had also their own custom APIs to search and retrieve recordings (and this was the way distributors were recommending), but this is not related to ONVIF.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this small script for testing purpose while working on ONVIF profile G to get the recordings. It shows all the steps you need and can be rewritten in C++ using your SOAP framework.

```
#! /bin/bash

read_dom()
{
    local IFS=\>
    read -d \< ENTITY CONTENT
}

curl --user user:passwd -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction:"  -d @FindRecordings.xml -X POST http://CameraIP/onvif/search_service > find_rec.xml
token=""

while read_dom; do
    if [[ $ENTITY = "tse:SearchToken" ]]; then
        token="$CONTENT"
        echo "search token = $token"
    fi
done < find_rec.xml

request="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
<GetRecordingSearchResults xmlns=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver10/search/wsdl\">
<SearchToken>$token</SearchToken>
<MinResults>1</MinResults>
<WaitTime>PT5S</WaitTime>
</GetRecordingSearchResults>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>"

echo "$request" > GetRecordingSearchResults.xml
sleep 1 # hacky tempo
curl --user user:passwd -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction:" -d @GetRecordingSearchResults.xml -X POST http://CameraIP/onvif/search_service
```

FindRecordings.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <FindRecordings xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/search/wsdl">
            <Scope>
                <RecordingInformationFilter xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema">boolean(//Track[TrackType = "Video"])</RecordingInformationFilter>
            </Scope>
            <KeepAliveTime>PT10S</KeepAliveTime>
        </FindRecordings>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Basically, you ask for a search token after a first find recordings request. From there you build a get recordings search result request to get the recording list.
Of course you can adapt the requests to your specific needs.

Hope this helps.